# can we store information in the KeyPairGeneratorSpec before installation so that it can be access from the app directly at the time of installation

Tags: java, android, keystore

I need to store some secure date in the app . so i am using KeyPairGeneratorSpec for that . because sqlite and shared preference can be hacked through root devices . but i want app in which the data is pre stored in the keystore and i can get it any time without saving it after installation . so that my key always remain secure .

Or is there any other way that i can store my data in the app and it can't be hacked through rooted mobile or decompiling .

I am using key store cause i found that [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html) that keystore can be used to sensitive information

Comment: It depends on what kind of data you want to secure. If you really want to secure sensitive data you have to look into `encrypting` your data.Just an idea: You could ship your app with a KeyStore which has an encryption key, and you would encrypt your data, and store the encrypted data. So, even if rooted devices get access to the data, they see rumbled encrypted string, which can only be decrypted using your key, which is inside the KeyStore. But you have to take measures on securing the KeyStore password.